# Window pop is not getting open in cypress for attachment testing

Tags: cypress

"Cypress Automation tool "when i am trying to open click on any element like button which open window pop up for attachments then button is getting click but window pop up is not getting open In Cypress. Help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: We can help you with it, but you need to share [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Note that you wouldn't be able to test/instrument new windows or tabs in Cypress even if it did work.